# split() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code:

```
  function _filter() {
    var url = window.location;
    alert(url);
    alert(url.split("/")[1]);
  }
```

When I launch it I get only one alert message:

> http://localhost:8000/index/3/1.

Why I don't get the second alert message?

Comment: check whether url.split("/")[1] is valid statement

Comment: `window.location` is a non-string object. You either need to call `toString()` or just grab `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding `.toString()` works and avoids this error:

**TypeError: url.split is not a function**

```
function _filter() {
    var url = window.location;
    alert(url);
    alert(url.toString().split("/")[2]);
}
```

When run on this very page, the output is:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: The `location` object has the `href` property intended just for this.

Comment: @Guffa: True href should be added with no need to use toString.

Answer (score 4):

The **location** object is the cause of this, **window.location is an object not a string** it is the location.href or location.toString().

```
  function _filter() {
    var url = window.location.href; // or window.location.toString()
    alert(url);
    alert(url.split("/")[1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `window.location` is not a string, you want the `href` property of the location object:

```
function _filter() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  alert(url);
  alert(url.split("/")[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Because your url is ans object so you need to convert this to string than you apply split function**

```
function _filter() {
    var url = window.location+ '';
    alert(url);
    alert(url.split("/")[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The index [1] is in between the two slashes of `http://` which is null and wont be alerted. Index [2] is the `localhost:8000` you're probably looking for.

Simple `window.location.hostname` should be useful too.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the `location` object has other properties that could be used to get parts of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how many pieces you get from splitting operation you can alert the .lenght of url.split, are you sure that the script doesn't block?

Use firebug to understand that

Answer (score 0):

url.split("/")[1] will equal to null. So, it alert(null) will not display msg.

Comment: Yeah. the location object didn't have split function.