# Why doesn't array === array.toString().split(",")

Tags: javascript

This is somewhat similar to [split() in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253561/split-in-javascript), but here's my question, and it's more theoretical than practical

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = ["abc", "def"]
```

When I do

```
debug(array === array.toString().split(","));
```

I get false, I tried == and that also gives false. I did a debug dump of the array and the joined/split array and they look exactly the same in output. What is the difference between them that's causing this to evaluate to false?

I think it's pretty clear for my code that I can just use array without having to do toString.split (it was necessary earlier, I think, not anymore), I'm just curious as to what's going on here.

Comment: use array.slice() instead of array.toString().split(",") when needed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `array.toString().split(",")` returns a new instance of the array. Arrays, being objects, are only equal if they are the exact same instance of the array:

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = [1,2];
var c = a;
alert(a == c); // true
alert(a == b); // false - not even loose comparison can save you
```

Answer (score 5):

Neither the `==` nor the `===` operator will inspect the contents of an array. Rather, they test whether the two operands reference the same array instance in memory. Notice:

```
['a', 'b'] === ['a', 'b']; // false

var arr = ['a', 'b'];
arr === arr;               // true
```

In other words, when you're comparing two different arrays, `==` or `===` will *always* return false;

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [MDN Doc for Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators),

> Note that an object is converted into a primitive if, and only if, its comparand is a primitive. If both operands are objects, they're compared as objects, and the equality test is true only if both refer the same object.

So, if we compare any two objects, then both `==` and `===` will check if they are one and the same. You can check that like this

```
console.log({} == {});
# false
console.log({} === {});
# false
console.log([] == []);
# false
console.log([] === []);
# false
```

I believe the reason could be, Arrays and Objects can be nested and it will be very difficult to check if two objects are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` and `===` operators do not compare the contents of Arrays. They just check to see if the two Arrays are actually the same Array object.

Answer (score 0):

Array is not a primitive type, they are not the same reference.

```
var a = ["a"];
var b = ["a"];
console.log(a == b); //false
```